# Eclipse , Tomcat, JPA - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

I got this exception:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class utils.DBConfig
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/Logger
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.<clinit>(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver.getPersistenceProviders(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:99)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:75)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at utils.DBConfig.contextInitialized(DBConfig.java:22)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.Logger
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1858)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1709)
    ... 19 more
```

I have added to build following jar files:

```
javax.persistence.jar
hibernate-entitymanager.jar
```

Someone know how to fix it?

Comment: check the jar file is in classpath or not?

Answer (score 0):

You miss the `jboss-common.jar` add it to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

**If you use Maven:**

il you have "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError xxxxxx" error, you search in google: "maven xxxxxx". you find [http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/...](http://mvnrepository.com)

copy/paste the dependency in pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Download a newer version of that Jar file from the [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging) and put it in your lib directory. Better use Maven.